# Exibir determinado vetor em uma lista 2D

Tags: python-2.7, lista

Possuo o seguinte problema:

- Tenho um vetor 2D e desejo que seja exibido somente o primeiro vetor ([250, 27.65863337187866, 93.38094023943002, 27.65863337187866]).
- Elaborei um código, porém ele está exibindo tudo.
- Abaixo o código:

---

```
lista_1 = [[250, 27.65863337187866, 93.38094023943002, 27.65863337187866], [0, 392, 327, 30, 348, 12, 64, 324]]

for i in lista_1:
    print (i)
```

---

Onde estou errando?

Grato pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posso ter percebido mal mas, se queres aceder só ao primeiro vector acedes ao index desse vector 
na lista prícipal:

```
lista_1 = [[250, 27.65863337187866, 93.38094023943002, 27.65863337187866], [0, 392, 327, 30, 348, 12, 64, 324]]
print(lista[0]) #[250, 27.65863337187866, 93.38094023943002, 27.65863337187866]
```

Neste caso, é o primeiro o primeiro vector interno, logo está no index `0`

Quando fazes:

```
for i in lista_1:
    print (i)
```

Estás a percorrer toda a lista imprimindo cada vector interno a cada volta do loop, imprimes todos.

Comment: É verdade Miguel! Já estou tão cansado de programar hoje, que me esqueci disso.
Mas, novamente agradeço sua ajuda.
Um grande abraço.

Comment: De nada @Danilo , estamos aqui para aprender. Mas devias ir descansar sendo assim lol. amanha já ficas de cabeça fresca

Comment: kkkk. É verdade. Vou parar por hoje.